# Translating activerecord collection for a dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

In a model I have some states

```
STATES = ["in_progress", "active", "archived"]
```

In my form I want a drop down/select with

```
In Progress, Active, Archived  for english
```

and

```
ชำระ , ขัน , ยื่น in Thai
```

What is the best way to handle this ?

One option I have thought of is the following

```
def self.states
  @states = {}
  STATES.each do |s|
    @states[s] = I18n.t(s)
  end
  @states
end
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Localization with rails. http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n

Comment: I've read the entire Localization guide and this is not covered, nor is it covered in the railscasts

Answer (score 2):

This is supported by simple_form:

In your view, you should just use

```
<%= f.input :state, collection: ["in_progress", "active", "archived"] %>
```

In your yaml file, you should have

```
simple_form:
  options:
    defaults:
      state:
        in_progress: In progress
        active: Active
        archived: Archived
```

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. I'm using formtastic, but many I can look at the code. !